# SignalProducer in ViewModel sends only one next event to observer in ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, reactive-cocoa

My app uses ReactiveCocoa 4.0 and I use the MVVM pattern.

I want to observe some values in the ViewModel from the ViewController. However I get only one initial next event from the MutableProperty in the ViewModel with the following observation in the ViewController

```
// in the ViewController
self.viewModel.player.producer.startWithNext { player in
    // Gets called only once
}
```

The mutable property in the ViewModel is defined as follows

```
let player = MutableProperty<Player>(Player())
```

On changes I change the value property of the player.

Strange thing: In the ViewModel I get all the update if I observe the SignalProducer in exact the same way I do from the ViewController.

```
// in the ViewModel
self.player.producer.startWithNext { player in
    // Gets called on every change to player.value
}
```

Any ideas what the reason could be?

**Edit**

As Cosyn suggested: I checked for other events such as completed or error - nothing was sent that could stop the signal. 
Also I checked the instance of the MutableProperty and the viewModel instance itself at a later point - all the same nothing changed or deinited.

Comment: Check if your view model is set to nil or some other value so the original value is deinited

Comment: Please see my Update. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You'd better provide minimal code that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: After spending a lot of time I found out that it was a very hidden structural error - I have to fix some architecture, but finally I fixed it. Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: @beseder I got the same problema and I couldn't find the solution. Can you give a tips where can I start to debugging. Thanks

Comment: For me it were multiple instances of ViewModels. Check if the instance you are subscribing on is the same, you want to be notified later on.